# Mpdf Erro ao Gravar Arquivo em um diretório

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou gerando arquivo pdf utilizando o **MPDF** porém preciso gravar ele em um diretório para que posteriormente via php eu possa pegar o arquivo e enviar por e-mail estou gerando o arquivo da seguinte forma

```
$dir = strtolower(__dir__.'/_assets/tmp');      
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/_assets/tmp']);
$mpdf->setdisplaymode('fullpage'); 
$mpdf->writehtml($html); 
$mpdf->output('teste.pdf',$dir);
```

Porém está dando o seguinte erro:

> [Sun Sep 15 12:15:50.056922 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 26464] [client ::1:59214] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Mpdf\MpdfException: Incorrect output destination /VAR/WWW/HTML/SISTEMA/_ASSETS/TMP in /var/www/html/sistema/_vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php:9465\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/sistema/pdftermo.php(133): Mpdf\Mpdf->Output('teste.pdf', '/VAR/WWW/HTML/S...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/sistema/_vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php on line 9465

Alguém saberia me orientar em que estou fazendo de errado ou como contornar o problema?

Comment: Pelo o que informa no erro ` Incorrect output destination /VAR/WWW/HTML/SISTEMA/_ASSETS/TMP` parece que esse caminho não existe.já conferiu se essa pasta existe e se tem permissão de escrita pelo php?

Comment: Sim a pasta existe inclusive verifiquei as permissões de leitura e escrita da mesma e esta liberada completamente

Comment: Inclusive já tentei somente colocar no lugar da variável dir coloquei o parâmetro 'F' e mesmo assim não consigo realizar o processo.